# How to upvote my question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

I have posted a question on SO but got no answer so far. Is it possible to upvote it myself so it may be seen by more people? If so, how can I upvote a question? I'm a new member.

Comment: You can't upvote your own question... this is not Reddit.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions Besides that you might want to exercise some patience. The only question you've asked without an answer seems to be 7 hours old now. (Unless you're referring to another question).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot upvote your own questions or answers. If you want to give the question more attention, try editing it to improve it (add more details, for example).

If you had more reputation, you could also offer [bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to give your question more attention.